# Does Kendo UI have a simple list component?

Tags: kendo-ui

I am looking for a simple list component, similar to the HTML listbox (or Bootstrap "List group".)

Does such a component exist?

If not which component can be used for this purpose?

Thanks

Comment: you could try on [kendo listview](http://dojo.telerik.com/AWOBU), but offcourse you need to apply css style by yourself

Comment: Kendo also has a theme roller or many prebuilt themes.

Comment: try this http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/listview/index

Comment: I have checked the demo for ListView. This is not similar to a simple list. I found something close to what I am looking for here: http://jqueryuivskendoui.com/demos/widgets.html (see ListView heading). However, I do not want the pager showing. Just a simple list that you can scroll, like a HTML listbox with kendo style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListView is Kendo's version of simple list. In demos on Telerik site, almost every listView has template with image. But simple listView looks as you want. I just add padding, to make it more readable:

Example: http://dojo.telerik.com/AyIwU/2

[image]

EDIT: Example with max-height and scroll: http://dojo.telerik.com/AyIwU/6

Comment: But how can you limit the number of elements displayed, and then also have a scrollbar to view further elements? It looks like it cannot be done.

Comment: Well, you can so it using CSS and max-height and overflow-y: auto properties. But you need to know the height of items you want to show. Look at the second example that I added.